# How do I loop through every table and alter the PK column like so? (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql, postgresql-12

Using psql in Postgres 12, I need to alter every column in every table of my database that's:

- int/bigint
- not null
- primary key

to:

- identity column
- auto-increment
- with default value starting at max value of current rows

I know this should be doable using PL/PgSQL, but I'm not familiar with it.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest you do is to start up `psql` using the -E option.

This will give you a "blow-by-blow account" of the SQL that's used to perform operations in `psql`.

From issuing the command `man psql`:

> -E
> --echo-hidden
>
> - Echo the actual queries generated by \d and other backslash commands. You can use this to study psql's internal operations. This
>   is equivalent to setting the variable ECHO_HIDDEN to on.

Then, perform your desired operations on a sample table in `psql` and copy and paste the resultant "background" SQL into your editor of choice. Then write a `PL/pgSQL` routine that cycles through the tables you wish to change which does the same thing - monkey-see, monkey-do!

As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, this request has been cross-posted (to StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845307/in-postgres-12-how-to-change-pk-columns-into-identity-using-dynamic-sql)). As an advanced PL/pgSQL question, it probably belongs here. So, could you please put a line at the top of your question on StackOverflow pointing here and telling people that any answers are to be put here and **not** on StackOverflow. This eliminates duplication of effort on the part of those trying to help you - thanks! Please see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/651136) on the topic.

p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: It seems Hmong Bong already has some code for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845307

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - ah, cross-posted! I'll put in a word about cross-posting in my answer... Thanks for the heads-up!